# Android IAB v3 testing and building

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm implementing IAB v3 into my application and I have done following steps:

1. Published signed APK into Alpha testing and added a test purchase product
2. Created a Google group which are allowed to be testers and added a test account into the group
3. Accepted to be a tester in my device
4. Took example code from TrivialDrive example into my application

IabHelper setup is OK but says there are no SKUs.

So now I'm trying to figure out that with what package can the IAB feature be developed further. The documentation says that the package must be the Google Play version, someone say that you can build signed package all over but must use same keystore for signing the package.

Isn't there a fast to to just launch the application with Eclipse **Run As** Android Application, so I can see logs and use debug mode if I want?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Looks like the purchases can be done with simply launching the app with Eclipse, not sure if the debug keystore which I made from my release keystore has affect on this. The SKU ids must be hard coded in the client/own server so I misunderstood the IabHelper query part.

Comment: Did you create sku Ids on play store for this app ? If not then create it and use that SKU Id in your project.

Comment: Hmm, so the example code just queries already owned items? Do you have to hard code SKU id for purchase buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample sku id for testing inApp purchase.

```
static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";
```

Here is good tutorial.
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial